# Compile php 8.1 with icu new version fails

Tags: php, centos, icu, intl

I'm compiling php 8.1.20 on centos 7 and trying to do it with the updated `ICU` for intl extension version 73.2. ICU compiled without problems. For php running make without `ICU_LIBS="/usr/local/libicu/lib"` succeeds.
Running make with `ICU_LIBS="/usr/local/libicu/lib"` option fails.

https://pastebin.com/iPHbZJpq

I see in the makefile that the ICU libraries of version 73.2 are configured, but the error also shows the use of version 50.2
This is because itsu 50.2 is installed through the yam

```
rpm -qa | grep icu
libicu-50.2-4.el7_7.x86_64
libicu-devel-50.2-4.el7_7.x86_64
```

Configuring with these options:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/libicu/lib
CC=/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/bin/gcc \
CXX=/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/bin/g++ \
CFLAGS="-O3 -march=nocona -mtune=nocona -funroll-all-loops -m64 -pipe -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -mmmx -msse2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse" \
CXXFLAGS="-O3 -march=nocona -mtune=nocona -funroll-all-loops -m64 -pipe -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -mmmx -msse2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse" \
ICU_LIBS="/usr/local/libicu/lib" \
LIBS=-lpthread \
    ./configure \
    --prefix=/usr/local/php-8.1.20 \
    --enable-fpm \
    --with-openssl \
    --with-zlib \
    --with-zlib-dir \
    --with-bz2 \
    --enable-ctype \
    --enable-calendar \
    --with-curl \
    --with-mhash \
    --enable-sockets \
    --enable-sysvmsg \
    --enable-sysvsem \
    --enable-sysvshm \
    --with-zip \
    --enable-mbstring \
    --enable-bcmath \
    --with-iconv \
    --enable-sigchild \
    --enable-gd \
    --with-jpeg \
    --with-freetype \
    --enable-mysqlnd \
    --with-mysqli \
    --with-pdo-mysql \
    --with-gettext \
    --with-ldap \
    --with-pdo-pgsql \
    --with-pgsql \
    --enable-intl
```

OS:

```
Linux somehost 3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Oct 18 17:15:30 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

gcc version:

```
gcc version 9.3.1 20200408 (Red Hat 9.3.1-2) (GCC)
```